# specific newline approach

Tags: c++, newline

How would I make a newline character after every 6 numbers? I've tried but I can't seem to not have every number on their own line as opposed to 6 numbers on their own line.
Thank you.

```
void Fibonacci(int length)
{
    int arr[20] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21,
                    34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377,
                     610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181};


    for (int i = length-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        cout<<setw(5)<<arr[i];
        cout<<"\n";

    }

}
```

Comment: Apart from the given answer, you should check if the given length argument is valid with reference to the size of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You provided an initializer of 19 elements to a 20 elements array, the array initialization is equivalent to:

   ```
   int arr[20] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21,
                   34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377,
                    610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 0};
   //                                           ^ Element No. 20
   ```

   The last element is value initialized to `0`, that's where the `0` before `4184` when calling `Fibonacci(20)` comes from.
2. Sure it's possible. Something like `if (i % 5 == 0) {std::cout << std::endl;}`

Comment: Oh wow... I feel so idiotic. I've been staring at this for hours and it was that simple...